# Как получить значение из всех созданных динамических view?

Tags: android, view, dynamic

На вход от сервера получаем xml.
В нем указаны field - type (например: first_name - edit, sex-groupbox и т.д.), наименование tabhost-ов и др. знач.

Далее, case "type": создаётся view этого типа.

Создаются view элементы(edittext, groupbox, date..) разного кол-во в зависимости от данных с сервера в нескольких tab-ов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: я хочу в onclick(save) получить в массиве все значения view из всех tab-ов.
Как я могу реализовать это?
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Нужно все создаваемые вью вставлять в список. При сохранении проходить по списку циклом и забирать значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам приходится такое делать, то скорей всего проблема **UX**.
Но если вы всетаки думаете, что это нормал, тогда самое простое решение это при изменнеии любого поля сохранять его значение в переменную, при кнопке Save использовать сохраненные данные.

Иначе вам придется бороться с особенностью жизненного цикла разных компонентов системы(activity, fragment) и биться за то, чтоб они всегда были живы, а ещё и хранили актуальный ViewState -> Занятие так себе я скажу. Те простыми словами, когда будете обращаться к View из 1tab, находясь на 3tab, нет гарантии, что это View будет хранить, ранее веденные данные, а может быть её и нет сейчас.

Как это реализовать, иной ворпос, ибо решений мб большое множество, принцип останеться c тем что я написал в самом вначале.

Comment: UX тут не при делах. Тут есть вполне понятный кейс - получение xml с сервера и динамическое создание интерфейса по этому xml. Так что получение значений всех динамически созданных элементов - это особенность программной реализации именно этого кейса

Comment: Это никак не влияет на ответ. Могу написать подругому, прилетает кривая xml, какая разница откуда. Если такой кейс, окей, я ответил принцип будет один.